# static linking breaks debug executable on windows (mingw)

Tags: windows, debugging, mingw, qt-creator, static-linking

Our C++ project uses mixed dynamic (Qt) and static (ffmpeg, portaudio) libraries. At the moment I'm trying to port it to windows and the debug executable produced by mingw (via QtCreator) refuses to start (the error is such-and-such is not a valid executable). The release executable with the same linkage starts (but has some problems I would like to debug).

To narrow down the possible cause of the problem I made a dummy project that does nothing, just links to the same set of libraries and it has exactly the same problem. As long as I disable linking to both static libraries debug executable works, as soon as I enable any one of them the debug executable is broken.

I haven't tried building dll versions of ffmpeg and portaudio yet, but I would like to understand what's going wrong with the case as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a nasty bug in the ld linker in the MinGW package that's included in some Qt downloads.

The ld linker that's included with the MinGW 4.4.0 package has a bug in the default linker script for placement of the `.debug_pubtypes` section, which is where symbols or some debug information gets stored. The linker script causes that section to get placed at a virtual address that the loader doesn't like (or something like that). Sometimes - if you don't have symbols in the image, or if the symbols are small enough (or maybe there's some other factor) the problem doesn't show up.

You have a couple of options:

- use the `-T <scriptfile>` option to specify a correct linker script to ld
- upgrade to a newer version of ld (version 2.21 that comes with MinGW 4.5.2 works fine).

Here's the default linker script from ld 2.21, which should work if you pass it in to the version you have (unfortunately my notes don't say what the version number of the ld with the problem is - if you could drop a comment about that so I can update my notes, I'd appreciate it).

```
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
SEARCH_DIR("/c/temp/gcc/dest/i686-pc-mingw32/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/c/temp/gcc/dest/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Make the virtual address and file offset synced if the alignment is
     lower than the target page size. */
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);
  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
     *(.init)
    *(.text)
    *(SORT(.text$*))
     *(.text.*)
    *(.glue_7t)
    *(.glue_7)
     ___CTOR_LIST__ = .; __CTOR_LIST__ = . ;
            LONG (-1);*(.ctors); *(.ctor); *(SORT(.ctors.*));  LONG (0);
     ___DTOR_LIST__ = .; __DTOR_LIST__ = . ;
            LONG (-1); *(.dtors); *(.dtor); *(SORT(.dtors.*));  LONG (0);
     *(.fini)
    /* ??? Why is .gcc_exc here?  */
     *(.gcc_exc)
    PROVIDE (etext = .);
     *(.gcc_except_table)
  }
  /* The Cygwin32 library uses a section to avoid copying certain data
     on fork.  This used to be named ".data".  The linker used
     to include this between __data_start__ and __data_end__, but that
     breaks building the cygwin32 dll.  Instead, we name the section
     ".data_cygwin_nocopy" and explictly include it after __data_end__. */
  .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __data_start__ = . ;
    *(.data)
    *(.data2)
    *(SORT(.data$*))
    *(.jcr)
    __data_end__ = . ;
    *(.data_cygwin_nocopy)
  }
  .rdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.rdata)
             *(SORT(.rdata$*))
    ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = .;
    __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = .;
    *(.rdata_runtime_pseudo_reloc)
    ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
    __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
  }
  .eh_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.eh_frame)
  }
  .pdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.pdata)
  }
  .bss BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __bss_start__ = . ;
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    __bss_end__ = . ;
  }
  .edata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.edata)
  }
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.debug$S)
    *(.debug$T)
    *(.debug$F)
    *(.drectve)
     *(.note.GNU-stack)
     *(.gnu.lto_*)
  }
  .idata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* This cannot currently be handled with grouped sections.
    See pe.em:sort_sections.  */
    SORT(*)(.idata$2)
    SORT(*)(.idata$3)
    /* These zeroes mark the end of the import list.  */
    LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
    SORT(*)(.idata$4)
    __IAT_start__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$5)
    __IAT_end__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$6)
    SORT(*)(.idata$7)
  }
  .CRT BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___crt_xc_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XC*))  /* C initialization */
    ___crt_xc_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xi_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XI*))  /* C++ initialization */
    ___crt_xi_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xl_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XL*))  /* TLS callbacks */
    /* ___crt_xl_end__ is defined in the TLS Directory support code */
    ___crt_xp_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XP*))  /* Pre-termination */
    ___crt_xp_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xt_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XT*))  /* Termination */
    ___crt_xt_end__ = . ;
  }
  .tls BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___tls_start__ = . ;
    *(.tls)
    *(.tls$)
    *(SORT(.tls$*))
    ___tls_end__ = . ;
  }
  .endjunk BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* end is deprecated, don't use it */
    PROVIDE (end = .);
    PROVIDE ( _end = .);
     __end__ = .;
  }
  .rsrc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.rsrc)
    *(SORT(.rsrc$*))
  }
  .reloc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.reloc)
  }
  .stab BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.stab)
  }
  .stabstr BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.stabstr)
  }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section.  Unlike other targets that fake this by putting the
     section VMA at 0, the PE format will not allow it.  */
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_aranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_aranges)
  }
  .debug_pubnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_pubnames)
  }
  .debug_pubtypes BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_pubtypes)
  }
  /* DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_info BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_info) *(.gnu.linkonce.wi.*)
  }
  .debug_abbrev BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_abbrev)
  }
  .debug_line BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_line)
  }
  .debug_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_frame)
  }
  .debug_str BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_str)
  }
  .debug_loc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_loc)
  }
  .debug_macinfo BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_macinfo)
  }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions.  */
  .debug_weaknames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_weaknames)
  }
  .debug_funcnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_funcnames)
  }
  .debug_typenames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_typenames)
  }
  .debug_varnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_varnames)
  }
  /* DWARF 3.  */
  .debug_ranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_ranges)
  }
  /* DWARF 4.  */
  .debug_types BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_types) *(.gnu.linkonce.wt.*)
  }
}
```

I don't mind telling you that I had to go through about a week of pain to figure this out. Windows doesn't give any real help at all about the reason it thinks the executable is invalid, and debugging - even with cdb or WinDBG from the "Debugging Tools for Windows" -  is little help. Windows seems to make the determination that the PE is invalid from deep within the bowels of the loader in the NT kernel, and doesn't give any information that I could find about the reason (it would have been nice to have something put into the event log or something).

I ultimately figured out this problem using Wine's (!!) tracing facility. I wonder if the 'checked' version of Windows would give more information about the problem, but I was having a hell of a time getting that downloaded and installed.

Comment: I have QtCreator 2.2.1 with mingw 4.4 which includes ld 2.19.1.

Comment: Hmm... while the test binary now runs when statically linked, the project itself still doesn't.

Comment: The above comment was after having built / linked with ld 2.21 from MinGW 4.5.x. If I add `QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS = -Wl,-T $$PWD/linker-script.txt` with the script you provided the problem appears to be solved for the large project as well.

Comment: I don't see why you'd have to specify a linker script when using ld 2.21, since it should have that script bound to it as a default. If you dump the default script using `ld --verbose > somefilename` does it compare the same as the script I posted (maybe different distributions of MinGW use different scripts)? But if you're working with the `QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS` setting, I guess it doens't matter.

Comment: Ah, got it, I still had wrong mingw in my PATH so some executables where picked up there. It seems tool chain selector is slightly broken in this respect - it isn't enough to point to the compiler from a tool chain, I need to add its 'bin' directory to the PATH separately.

Comment: Aha, and that in turn was caused by my build environment's using a custom PATH - only in this case changing the tool chain doesn't seem to affect it.